# UIPickerView disable row selection

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I want to disable the selection of certain rows in my `UIPickerView`. Like in the Coundown timer, where you try to choose 0, it doesn't let you and slips back up to 1. Or how you can limit the date in the `Date Picker`...

How do a disable rows in a `UIPickerView`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `UIPickerView` delegate method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

you can check if this selection is valid and scroll to the appropriate row if it is not (using pickerview's

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method.)

It looks that standard Clock application works this way.