# Swift UIPickerView disable component

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm having following UI:
[image]

Is it possible to disable only the last two components if the switch is used? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You can look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565743/uipickerview-disable-row-selection

Comment: I saw this post, but this is not what I want to do. It makes no sense to take a time if the whole day is switched on so I want to disable it. Scrolling to another time makes no sense for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not disable the components. However you can reload picker using `reloadAllComponents` method and you should reload only required components. Do not load time components.

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable the components. However you can try these solutions.

First solution:

```
var selectedRow3 = 3
var selectedRow4 = 3

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            switch component {
    case 3:
        myPicker.selectRow(selectedRow3, inComponent: component, animated: true)
    case 4:
        myPicker.selectRow(selectedRow4, inComponent: component, animated: true)

    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Second solution:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    switch component {
    case 3:
        return 1
    case 4:
        return 1
    default:
        return 10
    }
}
```