# Set background color of UIPickerView row

Tags: ios, swift

I've two questions about picker view.

How can I set a pickerview background color for a specific row? I'm trying to make "sections" which will have another background color. Also, how can I make sure they are unscrollable? I mean, the user should not be able to "stop" on that choice, the app should just scroll down to the next available one.

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    if WhatBool == true{

    }
}
```

I currently have this row. When I googled around on this issue I could not find anything that was actually working and not for a specific row. Am I doing wrong? How do I create sections in a pickerview? Everything seemed to be outdated so I would love to get some input on this.

I guess I should change this kind of stuff in viewForRow. But I'm completely stuck right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        var label:UILabel

        if let v = view as? UILabel{
            label = v
        }
        else{
            label = UILabel()
        }
        label.backgroundColor = component == 0 ? .red : .purple
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)

        label.text = arrayOfCountries[row]

        return label
    }
```

For the different backgrounds try this logic it will work & for disabling particular component follow this following answer

[Swift UIPickerView disable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853186/swift-uipickerview-disable-component?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. It does work but for all. I just wanna set a specific row, is that possible?